# CentOS, PHP file is running from browser, not from cron daemon

Tags: cron, php

I am working on CentOS.

I have created a PHP file which run from browser

```
http://mydomain.com/backupfile/dobackup.php
```

I have added the script from crontab and made the file executable, but it is not running

```
30 0 * * * /var/www/vhost/mydomain.com/httpdocs/backupfile/dobackup.php
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add shebang at the top of your code

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: ... and make sure to `chmod +x` the file.

Answer (score 3):

Or just execute php parser with script as an argument

```
30 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhost/mydomain.com/httpdocs/backupfile/dobackup.php
```